# A proper way to create dictionary from df or the way for computing jaccard similarity

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a df with more than 8000 columns. Each column (except first) represent binary value of 0 or 1.

```
|Name| t1| t2| t3|...| t4|  
| ..aa.. | 0 | 0 | 1 |...| 0 |  
| ..bb.. | 0 | 0 | 0 |...| 0 |  
| ..cc.. | 1 | 0 | 0 |...| 0 |
```

My goal is to compute jaccard index between aa,bb,cc for what I need values stored in list and that's why I'm gonna use dictionary.

The dictionary must look like this:

```
{'aa': [0,0,1,...,0], 'bb': [0,0,0,...,0],...}
```

How can I achieve such result when dict key=df index and value is a row represented as list?

Comment: *index* or `Name` column (after all)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest index is the Name column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a dictionary by zipping both the `Name` column and the rest of the dataframe and calling the `dict` constructor from the resulting tuples:

```
dict(zip(df.Name, df.loc[:,'t1':].values.tolist()))
# dict(zip(df.index, df.loc[:,'t1':].values.tolist())) # if name is the index
# {'aa': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'bb': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'cc': [1, 0, 0, 0]}
```

---

Input data:

```
   Name    t1     t2     t3     t4
0   aa      0      0      1      0
1   bb      0      0      0      0
2   cc      1      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
{k: list(v.values()) for k, v in df.set_index('Name').to_dict('index').items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

set `Name` as index and Transpose then do [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df.set_index('Name').T.to_dict('list')
```

If Name is the index just do:

```
df.T.to_dict('list')
```

---

```
{'aa': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'bb': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'cc': [1, 0, 0, 0]}
```